# Calculating $f^n(j)$ from $f(j)= \frac {a (j - i) + (a - ij) b} {(a - ij) + (j - i) b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let a function $f(j)=\frac{a x+yb}{y+xb}$ where $x=j-i;y=a-ij$. Now how can I calculate the general expression for $f^n(j)$ ? I tried calulating by induction but it is very hard to find a pattern. For instance $f^2(j)=\frac{ax_1+y_1b}{y_1+x_1b}$ where $x_1=2(j-i)(a-ij) ; y_1=(a-ij)^2+a(j-i)^2)$; $f^3(j)=\frac{ax_2+y_2b}{y_2+x_2b}$ where $x_2=(j-i)(a^2(j-i)^2+3(a-ij)^2) ; y_2=(a-ij)(3a(j-i)^2+(a-ij)^2)$ and so on. In other words, if $f^n(j)=\frac{ax_n+y_nb}{y_n+x_nb}$, what are $x_n$ and $y_n$ respectively?